# Verify with a table fieldname:possible_values if other tables value are in it and populate a field

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of tables for which I have table with possible values for most of the field. I want to create a field in each of the table that contains the column names of the column that contain non-accepted value.

Below is a test ground that correpond to what I want to do.

The expected result is :

```
Table foo
a  | b | c      | check
a  | 1 | foobar |
b  | 1 | foobaz |
ab | 1 | foofoo | a c

Table bar
a  | x      | y  | check
a  | foobar | 3  |
b  | foobaz | 2  |
ab | foofoo | 2  | x
```

The predefined check looks like that

```
table_name | field | permittedvalue
foo        |a      |a
foo        |a      |b
foo        |b      |NC
foo        |c      |foobar    
foo        |c      |foobaz 
bar        |a      |a
bar        |a      |b
bar        |a      |ab
bar        |b      |foo
bar        |b      |bar
bar        |c      |NC
```

I need it inside a function that takes the table_name as parameter.

```
create table foo (
a character varying,
b int,
c character varying);

insert into foo values('a',1,'foobar');
insert into foo values('b',1,'foobaz');
insert into foo values('ab',2,'foofoo'); -- Not an accepted value in table check_foo

create table bar (
a character varying,
x character varying,
y int);

insert into bar values('a','foo',3);
insert into bar values('b','bar',2);
insert into bar values('ab','foobar',2);-- Not an accepted value in table check_foo

create table check_foo(tablename character varying,
                      field character varying,
                      permittedvalue character varying);

insert into check_foo values('foo','a','a');
insert into check_foo values('foo','a','b');
insert into check_foo values('foo','b','NC'); -- 'NC' means the column is not concerned so must not be validated
insert into check_foo values('foo','c','foobar');    
insert into check_foo values('foo','c','foobaz');  
insert into check_foo values('bar','a','a');
insert into check_foo values('bar','a','b');
insert into check_foo values('bar','a','ab');
insert into check_foo values('bar','b','foo');
insert into check_foo values('bar','b','bar');
insert into check_foo values('bar','c','NC');
```

Comment: Anyone has an answer?